# C++ assembler output - how are references implemented

Tags: c++, assembly, reference

Toolchain for c++ and assembler: GNU

I have the following C++ code:

```
int main(void)
{
  int i = 33, j = 66;
  swap(i,j);

  cout << i << ", " << j << endl;

  return(0);
}
```

If I now check the assembler code generated I get in the area of the `swap` call the following:

```
movl    $33, -24(%rbp)
movl    $66, -20(%rbp)
leaq    -20(%rbp), %rdx
leaq    -24(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rdx, %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZSt4swapIiEvRT_S1_
movl    -20(%rbp), %ebx
movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
```

And the swap routine itself is:

```
_ZSt4swapIiEvRT_S1_:
.LFB1232:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
movq    %rsp, %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 6
movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
movl    (%rax), %eax
movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
movl    (%rax), %edx
movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
movl    %edx, (%rax)
movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
movl    %edx, (%rax)
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

So - since I am not that familiar with assembler - does that mean that for references the address of the variables is given directly to the function? And this would mean that they are not passed through the stack (which makes sense, because that what references should be)?

What does this do? (in the area around the call):

```
movq    %rdx, %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
```

Comment: Just plain pointers, LEAQ generates the value.  Your last snippet is unnecessary register jostling to pass the arguments through rsi and rdi.  Looking at unoptimized code isn't that interesting.

Comment: OK... which optimization would you suggest to get rid of "unnecessary register jostling" (but still keeping the interessting pare - calling a function using references)? Because if I add flag "-O1" then swap is optimized away and the values are directly given to stdout (which makes sense)...

Comment: @Michael even though it was optimized away at the call site, the body of the function should have been emitted unless you gave it internal linkage, look for its name in the assembly. Or just don't call it at all, compile a file that provides only the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the compiler is concerned, references are simply pointers.  The difference between the two lies entirely in how the programmer uses them.

Comment: Not necessarily. A reference can be implemented to involve no indirection at all.

Comment: @sftrabbit An interesting claim. Do you have any references for that?

Comment: @Yakk Nice play on words :-) and yes, of course, a pointer would do as well.

Answer (score 5):

A reference is nothing more than a pointer, "just" with a different notation.

So, in the end the generated assembly code will be the same whether you use pointers or references

```cpp
void swap1(int &a, int &b)
{
    int tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

void swap2(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

```asm
_Z5swap1RiS_:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    movl    (%rsi), %edx
    movl    %edx, (%rdi)
    movl    %eax, (%rsi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

_Z5swap2PiS_:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    movl    (%rsi), %edx
    movl    %edx, (%rdi)
    movl    %eax, (%rsi)
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: [tag:COM] actually uses this fact to make interop with C easier. The `REFGUID` macro is defined as `const GUID *` in C and `const GUID&` in C++

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for writing a long answer, but I think assembly is the best way to understand how references are implemented by compilers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *ptrToI = &i;
    int &refToI = i;

    cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
    cout << "&i = " << &i << "\n";

    cout << "ptrToI = " << ptrToI << "\n";
    cout << "*ptrToI = " << *ptrToI << "\n";
    cout << "&ptrToI = " << &ptrToI << "\n";

    cout << "refToNum = " << refToI << "\n";
    //cout << "*refToNum = " << *refToI << "\n";
    cout << "&refToNum = " << &refToI << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output of this code is like this

```
i = 10
&i = 0xbf9e52f8
ptrToI = 0xbf9e52f8
*ptrToI = 10
&ptrToI = 0xbf9e52f4
refToNum = 10
&refToNum = 0xbf9e52f8
```

Lets look at the disassembly(I used GDB for this. 8,9 and 10 here are line numbers of code)

```
8           int i = 10;
0x08048698 <main()+18>: movl   $0xa,-0x10(%ebp)
```

Here `$0xa` is the 10(decimal) that we are assigning to `i`. `-0x10(%ebp)` here means content of `ebp` register –16(decimal).  `-0x10(%ebp)` points to the address of `i` on stack.

```
9           int *ptrToI = &i;
0x0804869f <main()+25>: lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x080486a2 <main()+28>: mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
```

Assign address of `i` to `ptrToI`. `ptrToI` is again on stack located at address `-0x14(%ebp)`, that is `ebp` – 20(decimal).

```
10          int &refToI = i;
0x080486a5 <main()+31>: lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x080486a8 <main()+34>: mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
```

Now here is the catch! Compare disassembly of line 9 and 10 and you will observer that ,`-0x14(%ebp)` is replaced by `-0xc(%ebp)` in line number 10. `-0xc(%ebp)` is the address of `refToNum`. It is allocated on stack. But you will never be able to get this address from you code because you are not required to know the address.

So; a reference does occupy memory. In this case it is the stack memory since we have allocated it as a local variable. How much memory does it occupy? As much a pointer occupies.

Now lets see how we access the reference and pointers. For simplicity I have shown only part of the assembly snippet

```
16          cout << "*ptrToI = " << *ptrToI << "\n";
0x08048746 <main()+192>:        mov    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x08048749 <main()+195>:        mov    (%eax),%ebx
19          cout << "refToNum = " << refToI << "\n";
0x080487b0 <main()+298>:        mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080487b3 <main()+301>:        mov    (%eax),%ebx
```

Now compare the above two lines, you will see striking similarity.  `-0xc(%ebp)` is the actual address of  `refToI` which is never accessible to you. In simple terms, if you think of reference as a normal pointer, then accessing a reference is like fetching the value at address pointed to by the reference. Which means the below two lines of code will give you the same result

```
cout << "Value if i = " << *ptrToI << "\n";
cout << " Value if i = " << refToI << "\n";
```

Now compare this

```
15          cout << "ptrToI = " << ptrToI << "\n";
0x08048713 <main()+141>:        mov    -0x14(%ebp),%ebx
21          cout << "&refToNum = " << &refToI << "\n";
0x080487fb <main()+373>:        mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
```

I guess you are able to spot what is happening here. If you ask for `&refToI`, the contents of `-0xc(%ebp)` address location are returned and `-0xc(%ebp)` is where `refToi` resides and its contents are nothing but address of `i`.

One last thing, Why is this line commented?

```
//cout << "*refToNum = " << *refToI << "\n";
```

Because `*refToI` is not permitted and it will give you a compile time error.